# Google DirectionsService: route summary field blank?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

The Google DirectionsService documentation states that it offers a disambiguating summary of each route returned for a given request:

> `summary` contains a short textual description for the route, suitable
>   for naming and disambiguating the route from alternatives.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Routes

However, in all of the results that we get back, the summary field is null, e.g.

```
     },
     "summary" : "",
     "warnings" : [
        "Walking directions are in beta.    Use caution – This route may be missing sidewalks or pedestrian paths."
     ],
     "waypoint_order" : []
  },
  {
     "bounds" : {
        "northeast" : {
           "lat" : 37.62679,
           "lng" : -122.2297699
        },
        "southwest" : {
           "lat" : 37.48454,
           "lng" : -122.401207
        }
     },
```

Does anyone else have this problem? Any idea how to fix it, e.g. an undocumented parameter or similar that needs to be set to get Google's summary of the results?

(Obviously we can come up with a schema to summarize each trip ourselves, but we were hoping to not have to do that — just one more thing to deal with.)

Comment: Are you requesting alternative routes?  What is your request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summary gives the name/s of the street  you use most, while following the route. Because you have set `walking` as travel mode it can happen that the most used "road" isn't a road, because you walk through the woods f.e. or has no name.

I used `driving` as travel mode most of the time and up to 90% of these the summary field contained a street or highway name.